# How to get span CLASS value into excel VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, class

https://www.similarweb.com/website/kcci.com

I`m trting to get the value inside this span:

```
<span class="rankingItem-value js-countable" data-value="31,504">#31,504</span>
```

My results should be 31,504.

I`m trying to run this code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click2()

Dim ieApp As Object
Set ieApp = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With ieApp
    .Navigate "https://www.similarweb.com/website/" & "kcci.com"
    .Visible = False
End With

Do While ieApp.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set allRowOfData = ieApp.document.getelementsbyclassname("rankingItem-value js-countable")

Dim myValue As String
myValue = allRowOfData.innerHTML

MsgBox myValue

Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I can`t get the value.
Can anyone help me understand what am i missing?

Comment: Ok i got it :)
Needed to add (0) here: Set allRowOfData = ieApp.document.getelementsbyclassname("rankingItem-value js-countable")(0)

Comment: Yes, because you can have multiple elements with that class as opposed to getElementById which should exist only once on the page